# Java regex to replace new Line with symbol

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace this input text

```
Line1
Line 2
Line 3.
```

TO become(Required o/p) 
Line1%%Line 2%%Line 3.

I used regex

```
string.replaceAll("[\\n]+[\\r]", "%%");
```

But it gives me o/p as

```
Line1   
Line 2  
Line 3.
```

Other regex I have tried so far-- `[\\t\\n\\r] , [\\n\\r]+ , [\\n]`
And all gives different o/p but not the one I need . Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to put `\r` and `\n` into 1 char class:

```
String result = "Line1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3.".replaceAll("[\r\n]+", "%%");
                                                         ^^^^^^^
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/LA64Vs). The `[\r\n]+` matches a sequence of 1 or more LF (`\n`) or CR (`\r`) symbols.

Note that you can get the same output with [`"[\\r\\n]+"`](https://ideone.com/4a2jkI) where `\n` and `\r` are passed as special regex escape sequences, while in the former example, literal CR and LF symbols are passed to the regex engine.

And another solution (starting with Java 8) is using [`"\\R+"`](https://ideone.com/6Jr5CX) (see [this reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum): *`\R`  Any Unicode linebreak sequence, is equivalent to `\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]`*). `\R` matches any *linebreak sequence* and `+` matches 1 or more occurrences of the quantified pattern.

**If you want to also get rid of leading/trailing space on the lines, use

```
replaceAll("\\s*[\r\n]+\\s*", "%%"));
//or
replaceAll("[^\\S\r\n]*[\r\n]+[^\\S\r\n]*", "%%"));
//or
replaceAll("[\\p{Zs}\t]*[\r\n]+[\\p{Zs}\t]*", "%%"));
// or
replaceAll("[\\s&&[^\n\r]]*[\r\n]+[\\s&&[^\n\r]]*", "%%"));
```

See [this IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/hrxw9e).

The `[^\\S\r\n]` (=`[\\s&&[^\n\r]]`) matches any whitespace matched with `\s` with the exception of `\r` and `\n`. The `[\\p{Zs}\t]` matches any horizontal whitespace (same as `\h` in PCRE/PHP).

Comment: I tried your way but it prints unwanted space in between 
O/p 
Line1 %%Line 2 %%Line 3.

I need  Line1%%Line 2%%Line3

Comment: That means you have a different input from the one you posted and that you need `"\\s*[\r\n]+"` or `"\\s*[\r\n]+\\s*"`. Or to make it only work linearly, `"[\t\\p{Zs}]*[\r\n]+[\t\\p{Zs}]*"`.

Comment: I get input from text area element in that some can use enter to skip line so thats why

Comment: I added several options to also remove leading/trailing spaces